# Joining subsite newsfeeds into master feed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, newsfeed

I have a Site Collection with ~7 subsites, each which will be utilizing the "Newsfeed" feature. Is there a way to pull all of these subsite newsfeeds into a parent site newsfeed? If not, are the newsfeed posts stored somewhere that I would be able to possibly build a web part to display the most recent posts across these subsites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint, there is a list named **Microfeed**. It is MySite MicroFeed Persistent Storage List and it is created by the Site Feed feature automatically. It stores the content and data from the default Newsfeed web part at the site home page (e.g. the conversation in Newsfeed ).

The path of Microfeed list:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/Lists/PublishedFeed
```

You can use a Content Search web part and build queries to display data from Microfeed in several sites (and subsites).

Example of queries:

```
path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/Lists/PublishedFeed"  ContentType:Post
```

Use **FullPostBody** managed property to display contents from newsfeed entries.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Is there somewhere I can learn more about setting these queries? I'm looking on docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint but don't see anything about `path:` ?

Comment: "Path" is a managed property. refer to the KQL query: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

Comment: Do you know which managed property I can use to a) redirect to the subsite where the post is coming from and b) Grab the Posting user's profile picture? I've browsed through the Property mapping options but everything seems to return errors